# SQL failure 155 from ODBC due to time format in column

Tags: sql, odbc

This query works in SQL management studio, but not in ODBC.

I get error: `“('ODBC SQL type -155 is not yet supported.  column-index=6  type=-155', 'HY106')”`

The query is below:

`select top 100 SType, * from dw.execution f join dw.station d on f.StID = d.StID where SType like '%test%'`

It appears that I need to drop column 6 from this query

Im not sure if SQL counts columns from 0 or 1, but column number 6 in SQL management studio query is named `TestSuiteStartTimestampUtc` therefore my assumption is due to the time format, which is confirmed in this post [ODBC SQL type -155 is not yet supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46405373/odbc-sql-type-155-is-not-yet-supported)

I dont need this particular column in my query, and I would like to drop it, however, it appears I can also cast it with something like
`CAST(TestSuiteStartTimestampUtc AS nvarchar(100)) as TestSuiteStartTimestampUtc`

I tried to do this, but I do not understand how to correctly include this in my query

Can someone please help correct the entire SQL query so that I can either

1. Drop this particular column in my query
2. Format it as char instead of timestamp so that query does not error out